# Partial derivative - Chain rule problem

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

I'm not really BAD at math, even though I'm not good. But What am I doing wrong here?

$U_x$ denotes partial derivative of $U$ with respect to $x$

Let $U(x,y)=F(f(x)+g(y))$ and $V(x,y)=lnU_x-lnU_y$

Find $V_x$

Answer sheet says that the answer is $\frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}$ But How come? I couldn't end up with that answer, what is wrong with my approach?

$$V_x=\frac{U_{xx}}{U_x}-\frac{U_{yx}}{U_y}$$

$$U_{xx}=F_{xx}(f(x)+g(y))f'(x)+F_x(f(x)+g(y))f''(x)\\
U_{yx}=F_{yx}(f(x)+g(y))f'(x)g'(y)\\
V_x=\frac{F_{xx}(f(x)+g(y))}{F_x(f(x)+g(y))}+\frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}-\frac{F_{yx}(f(x)+g(y))f'(x)}{F_y(f(x)+g(y))}$$

Isn't this the answer

Comment: When calculating $V_x$ that means you are deriving with respect to $x$. So what is then the derivative of $lnU_y$?

Comment: natural logarithm of the partial derivative of U with respect to y

Comment: Yes, I may not fully understand the problem, but as I interpret, $V_x$ means deriving with respect to $x$

Comment: Means partial derivative w.r.to x, if that's what you mean with deriving

Comment: Ok, To my understanding, deriving $U_y$ with respect to $x$ means you are deriving an function depending only on $y$ with respect to $x$. Doesn't that cancel? Or does $U_y$ still have $x$ terms in it?

Comment: imranfat, that is incorrect. $U_y=U_y(x,y)$, it can still be a function of x and y

Comment: @Canardini Ok, I misunderstood (notation). That makes sense then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake

$U_x=f'(x)F'(f(x)+g(y))$

$U_{xx}=f''(x)F'(f(x)+g(y))+f'(x)^2F''(f(x)+g(y))$

$U_y=g'(y)F'(f(x)+g(y))$

$U_{yx}=g'(y)f'(x)F''(f(x)+g(y))$

Then conclude with your result 
$V_x=\frac{U_{xx}}{U_x}-\frac{U_{yx}}{U_y}$

Comment: Isn't something wrong with your notation here, Shouldn't you write $F_{xx}$  or $F_{yy}$instead of $F''$

Comment: Since F is not a function of a one variable $F''$ does not make sense here

Comment: F takes as an argument a real, not a vector. we are using the chain rule.

Comment: the output of f+g which are real , is used as an input of F

Comment: let $f(x,y)=xy$
$f_x=y$ $f_y=x$ $

$f'$ does not make sense here

Comment: $F$ is a function of a single variabile, so no confusion using '.

Comment: what do you mean by output is real

Comment: @N74 Then, could you please tell $F$ is a function of which variable?

Comment: How did you define F in your exercise ?

Comment: $F(z)$ where $z=f(x)+g(y)$.

Comment: @Canardini That's the thing, it's not defined. That's where I get confused.

Can we just really define $F(z)$ where $z=f(x)+g(y)$ Are we sure?

Comment: I know you did not define it, but for sure it is a real not a vector, as it seems that f and g have values in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Canardini I mean we don't even know what x,y are? seriously . I hate taking courses from the economics department.

Comment: You exercise lacks of details. for example, we dont know anything about f and g, yet we assume that they are twice differentiable, as well as F. Also we divide by $f'(x)$, without assuming that it cannot be zero. Yet we can assume that everything is ok in this world. So for me , F takes values from $\mathbb{R}$,f and g returns values in$\mathbb{R}$,  and if we want to derive we can, if we want to divide, we can

Comment: @Canardini I'm a math major double with economics. This is the main theme of economics courses. Nothing seems true. I kinda got used to assuming pretty much everything. Hate it.

Comment: You can point this out to your lecturer